# How does piping affect stdin?

Tags: shell, pipe, tty, c, stdin

I want to write a C program, and I need to parse `stdin`. If I type `cat file.txt | grep -v match`, how does `stdout` from `cat` resolve with `-v match`? Are they concatenated? Are they two different strings? I ran `cat /dev/pts/0` and `file /dev/pts/0`, so I didn't find anything (seemingly) useful there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard definition for the main function of a C program is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Here, `argc` and `argv` are the command line arguments, `-v` and `match` for `grep` in this case. Note that they're **not** a single string, but the shell has already split the arguments to distinct strings (NUL/`\0` terminated, as usual in C). `argc` contains the number of arguments, and `argv` the arguments themselves.

Standard input on the other hand is just a `FILE *`, you can use it directly with any of the `stdio` functions. `fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)` etc.

---

I'm not sure where you got `cat /dev/pts/0`. It would read from that particular pseudo-terminal, possibly conflicting with reads by your shell on that same terminal. (Try to open two terminals, xterm, SSH sessions, screen, whatever. Then run `tty` on the first one, it shows the name of the terminal there, e.g. `/dev/pts/123`. Run `cat /dev/pts/123` (with the given name) in the second terminal, then try to type something in the first.)

Comment: I assumed the tty was a text file for some reason, so I tried to read it. When that didn't work, I checked what kind of file it was.

Comment: So `stdin` has the output of the piped command, and `argc`, `argv` have the options and stuff used with the command? Can `stdin` have the latter?

Comment: @MichaelChristensen, I would use the phrase "`stdin` is connected to the pipe", but yes. You could run something like `cat $(echo foobar)`, where the command substitution would take the output of `echo` and put it in the arguments of `cat`, so `cat` would see that `foobar` in `argv`. But that's a completely different construct from `echo foobar | cat`.

Answer (score 12):

A *pipe* is a buffer allocated in the kernel with file descriptors associated with the read and write ends.  When you run `cat file.txt | grep -v match`:

- The shell creates a pipe (using the `pipe()` system call)
- The shell `fork()`s. The child process uses the `dup2()` system call to close its standard output stream and to duplicate the write end of the pipe to standard output.  (After this, writes to standard output will go to the kernel buffer.) Then the child `exec()`s `cat` with the updated standard output.
- The shell `fork()`s again.  The child uses the `dup2()` system call to close its standard input stream and to duplicate the read end of the pipe to standard input.  (After this, reads from standard input will come from the kernel buffer.)  Then the child `exec()`s `grep` with the updated standard input.

At this point, both `cat` and `grep` are running.  If `grep` tries to read from standard input (the pipe) and the pipe is empty, the read will block.  If `cat` tries to write to standard output (again, the pipe) and the pipe is full, the write will block.  Otherwise, as `cat` writes to the buffer, `grep` can read from the buffer.

Comment: *The child process uses the dup2() system call to close its standard output stream and to ***duplicate the write end of the pipe to standard output.*** * How? Could you please explain that in more detail? As the manual of `dup2`, which says that ***dup2() makes newfd be the copy of oldfd, closing newfd first if necessary***. AFAIS, it seems that `dup2` the said goal.